# No ad config error code 3 in Admob. Test ads and live ads are showing in debug apk, but not showing in signed apk

Tags: android, admob

TestAds and production ads are showing in debug apk, but not showing when app is signed. Struck with this for 2 days in Android.
Getting the below response.

```
 "Code": 3,
  "Message": "No ad config.",
  "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
  "Cause": "null",
  "Response Info": {
    "Response ID": "null",
    "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
    "Adapter Responses": []
  }
```

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0' - my current version.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. Any luck? Did you solve it?

Comment: Hello there, im struggling with this also. Everythings are fine until  hit release the project with sign (or key.js). Do you have any solutions already?

Answer (score 0):

The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.
This error is caused by google server end and not from our side. So don't worry - it is going to vanish.